# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TF_DeleteStatus'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow is giving me this unresolved error:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f68d14b6668>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 532, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'TF_DeleteStatus'
```

The error has been discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3388). The problem is it is not showing up consistently. However, it is showing up in my terminal frequently. Has anybody managed to get around it.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on github. A fix is coming.

Answer (score 16):

You can run `import gc; gc.collect()` in the end of your code.

Comment: I just tried this for a simple Keras example based on http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/ . Alas, I still get the error.

Answer (score 8):

Answer from Github posted here to save time:

```
from keras import backend as K

# ... code
K.clear_session()
```

I added the `K.clear_session()` right before the `model.load_weights` call in my code and that worked.

Answer (score 7):

You need to delete the Tensorflow session to avoid that message. The simplest probably is to use a `with` statement:

```
from keras import backend as K

def main():
    with K.get_session():
        train()
        classify()
```

Answer (score 0):

write code in your tensorflow keras model...

```
from keras import backend as K
.
.
.
.
.
model.load_weights("modelname")
K.clear_session()
```